# Select only the root item of a html node

Tags: javascript

I have this html code.

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <a href="#" class="breadcrumb">Home</a>      
  <a class="breadcrumb" href="#">About</a>      
  <a class="breadcrumb" href="#">History</a>
  Message from our Founding Members  
</div>
```

Using javascript I want to get the text from the div ".breadcrumb". The problem is the a tag under the div also has a class with the same name, when I run this code:

```
var names = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb');
return [].map.call(names, function(name) {
  return name.textContent;
});
```

My first element of the array gets the textContent of all the a elements and also the div.
How can I do to get the text of only the div. In this case I want to return only "Message from our Founding Members". 
Is there a way to select only the root item of the html, when they have all the same class ?

Thanks

Comment: Use jQuery, and you will no have problems with selection DOM nodes.

Comment: if you can use jquery there is a simple way to do this
$("div .breadcrumb").html()
or
$("div .breadcrumb").text()

Comment: The problem is not that all nodes have that class, it's that `textContent` returns all text contents, including the children's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the text from the `<a>` tags with the `class="breadcrumb"`, you can do that by using more specific selectors that include the tag type like this:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div.breadcrumb a.breadcrumb");
var text = [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    text.push(items[i].textContent);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kVwH8/

---

If, what you're trying to do is to get the "Message from our Founding Members" text (I wasn't entirely clear from your original question), then you can do that like this::

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div.breadcrumb a.breadcrumb");
// get node after the last item (that should be the desired text node)
var txtNode = items[items.length - 1].nextSibling;
console.log(txtNode.nodeValue);   //  Message from our Founding Members
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kynuE/

Comment: @user15329422 - Added new option to my answer and reworded the solution.

Comment: I was trying to get the Message from our Founding Members. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use div.breadcrumb because that will give you divs with class breadcrumb, not a tags.

Comment: I tried that, still returns all because the a tags also have .breadcrumb class in it.

Comment: You may be able to use the :not('a.breadcrumb') pseudo-selector too. See more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Answer (score 0):

[You can do this](http://jsfiddle.net/r6xj3/):

```
var names = document.querySelectorAll('div.breadcrumb')[0].childNodes;

var text = Array.prototype.reduce.call(names,function(prev,node){
   if(node.nodeType === 3) return (prev || '' + node.textContent.trim());
});

console.log(text);
```

There are a lot of ES5 stuff here like [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) so better have those polyfills handy.